# Ember-data validation and associations

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

This seems to be coming up over and over for me and I wanted advice on how to deal with it. Pardon me as I write the examples in coffeescript.

```
App.Post = DS.Model.extend
    title: DS.attr('string')
    author: DS.belongsTo('App.Author')

App.Author = DS.Model.extend
    name: DS.attr('string')
    posts: DS.hasMany('App.Post')
```

I want to create an author and associated posts at the same time.

`author =  App.Author.createRecord({name: 'waldo'});`

`author.get('posts').createRecord({title: 'how to do the Ember'})`

alternatively

`post = App.Post.createRecord({author: author})`

The problem is, the Post model on my server validates the presence of author_id. So when I call `store.commit()`, `author` is submitted successfully, but `post` gets rejected because `post.get('author.id') //=> undefined`

**UPDATE**: The Author model also has a validation on the server that says it needs at least one post to be created so I can't call `store.commit()` before creating the post.

I have messed with transactions unsuccessfully. I will keep messing around with it, but this seems like a good question to have answered on S/O for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to do it in a transaction? If not, you could call `App.store.commit()` before you add the post-record to the author. If this does not solve your problem you may have async-troubles. In that case, you can hook up to the [didCreate](https://github.com/emberjs/data#record-lifecycle)-event on your Author-model. When that event fires the record has been created on the server and your model should have an id. If you add the posts at this stage your server should not complain.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I also have a validation that says an Author cannot be added without at least one post. (This is a pseudo example, it makes more sense in my app).

Can you give me an example of how to hook up `didCreate`. I understand the function is called, but I'm not sure how to bind to it so that I can call other actions after it has been called.

Comment: There is an example on didLoad in the linked documentation. Just replace `didload` with `didCreate`. Maybe you can create the `Post`first, and then, after is it commited, you can add an author with that post-id?

Comment: After conversation offline, I think what I really want to do is something like accept nested attributes in Rails. The transaction should be an all or nothing. Neither Author nor post should be saved without the other.